# Avoid duplicate POSTs with REST

Tags: rest, post, atomic

I have been using POST in a REST API to create objects. Every once in a while, the server will create the object, but the client will be disconnected before it receives the `201 Created` response. The client only sees a failed POST request, and tries again later, and the server happily creates a duplicate object...

Others must have had this problem, right? But I google around, and everyone just seems to ignore it.

I have 2 solutions:

A) Use PUT instead, and create the (GU)ID on the client.

B) Add a GUID to all objects created on the client, and have the server enforce their `UNIQUE`-ness.

A doesn't match existing frameworks very well, and B feels like a hack. How does other people solve this, in the real world?

Edit:

With Backbone.js, you can set a GUID as the id when you create an object on the client. When it is saved, Backbone will do a PUT request. Make your REST backend handle PUT to non-existing id's, and you're set.

Comment: How does the client see the failed POST request?

Comment: @TravisParks: It doesn't, technically. But it doesn't get the 201 Created response either, so the request fails. All HTTP APIs have functionality for that.

Comment: "server happily creates a duplicate object..." Then you have failing validation on your server side. Your server should always be checking for duplicates.

Comment: @JeremyB.: That is my point. Without a UUID sent from the client, the server has no way of knowing if they are accidental or intentional duplicates. Just setting a combined UNIQUE index of all the fields doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'd argue that all generated keys (server or client) are a hack. It's almost always better to use a natural key. When using a guid you just push the problem up a level. Perhaps the client is middleware and has clients of its own, for example. Without a natural key every layer above the one generating the keys will have problems with sending duplicates.

Comment: @SamuelDanielson: Is this something you have done in production? Wouldn't "natural keys" just move the problem into finding a natural key? Lot's of situations don't have any suitable natural keys. Also, there is the problem when you want to change the field that is used as a key. Messy.

Comment: @SamuelDanielson: Natural keys are generated ! The generated key suggested above identifies a requested action, which can be considered a resource as much as any other, albeit an ephemeral resource concerning a single user. The trick is to link the uniqueness of your request identifier to uniqueness in both the sending and receiving environments: On the client, a shopping cart can have only one active-or-successful "finalise-and-pay" request. On the server, an order can have only one active-or-successful "finalise-and-pay" action. I've added a little answer below to explore this further.

Comment: See also [this answer on the question "How to deal with timed out POST requests"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13839211/1347968).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with timed out POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316357/how-to-deal-with-timed-out-post-requests)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always use B -- detection of dups due to whatever problem belongs on the server side.

Comment: I think you might be right. The client GUID creation is simple enough to abstract away, and it requires very little changes on the server too. Solution A is a lot cleaner conceptually, but way too invasive to use with existing frameworks.

Comment: Is there a specific HTTP response code that should be returned in the case where a duplicate is found?

Comment: @ChrisNevill: You could send a `200 OK` instead of `201 Created`, since you didn't actually create a new object.

Comment: @ChrisNevill, @geon: In such a situation, I've followed Leonard Richardson's advice and returned `409 Conflict`.

Comment: "B -- detection" I cannot find anything relevant with this keyword. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: the "ID" in method B is called an `idempotency key`

Comment: What is a B -- detection?

Comment: It's just Option B -- create the GUID and be done with it. In any case, the GUID is arbitrary -- there's no particular advantage to creating it server side, but there are advantages to creating it client side

Answer (score 12):

Another solution that's been proposed for this is [POST Once Exactly (POE)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-poe-00), in which the server generates single-use POST URIs that, when used more than once, will cause the server to return a 405 response.

The downsides are that 1) the POE draft was allowed to expire without any further progress on standardization, and thus 2) implementing it requires changes to clients to make use of the new POE headers, and extra work by servers to implement the POE semantics.

By googling you can find a few APIs that are using it though.

Another idea I had for solving this problem is that of a conditional POST, which I described and asked for feedback on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911719/rest-prevent-creation-of-duplicate-resources-via-conditional-post).

There seems to be no consensus on the best way to prevent duplicate resource creation in cases where the unique URI generation is unable to be PUT on the client and hence POST is needed.

Answer (score 10):

Detection of duplicates is a kludge, and can get very complicated. Genuine distinct but similar requests can arrive at the same time, perhaps because a network connection is restored. And repeat requests can arrive hours or days apart if a network connection drops out.

All of the discussion of identifiers in the other anwsers is with the goal of giving an error in response to duplicate requests, but this will normally just incite a client to get or generate a new id and try again.

**A simple and robust pattern to solve this problem is as follows: Server applications should store all responses to unsafe requests, then, if they see a duplicate request, they can repeat the previous response *and do nothing else*.** Do this for all unsafe requests and you will solve a bunch of thorny problems. Repeat DELETE requests will get the original confirmation, not a 404 error. Repeat POSTS do not create duplicates. Repeated updates do not overwrite subsequent changes etc. etc.

"Duplicate" is determined by an application-level id (that serves just to identify the action, not the underlying resource). This can be either a client-generated GUID or a server-generated sequence number. In this second case, a request-response should be dedicated just to exchanging the id. I like this solution because the dedicated step makes clients think they're getting something precious that they need to look after. If they can generate their own identifiers, they're more likely to put this line inside the loop and every bloody request will have a new id.

Using this scheme, all POSTs are empty, and POST is used only for retrieving an action identifier. All PUTs and DELETEs are fully idempotent: successive requests get the same (stored and replayed) response and cause nothing further to happen. The nicest thing about this pattern is its Kung-Fu (Panda) quality. It takes a weakness: the propensity for clients to repeat a request any time they get an unexpected response, and turns it into a force :-)

I have a little google doc [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s0joc0yb6kXpXZGfdE9SRutoPQuK9RVa77f92xsXzrM) if any-one cares.

Comment: I highly doubt this really solves the problem you say it solves. You state that you don't want to work with a client generated id, because you fear the (poorly) implemented client will just create a new id for each request. But with your approach, it is still possible for a poorly implemented to just do the POST/PUT sequence for each insert. So you basically just complicated your REST API but didn't really get anything in return.

Comment: I say that I prefer server generated ids because it increases the likelihood of clients behaving responsibly. There are no guarantees, but the developers calling your api want to "do the right thing" just as much as you do, as a general rule. With this pattern, unambiguous interaction is at least possible. Directly addressing unsafe requests to "real" resources has led us into a world of pain and kludges.

Comment: I'm all for good style, but your solution includes an additional roundtrip just for conceptual soundness. And I'm actually very fond of the idea of non-centralized id's, which can be easily accomplished by using a random 128-bit UUID. Nevertheless, it surprises me that I can't seem to find an authoritative source that addresses this (very common - I'd say) problem.

Comment: I'm aware there's a big debate around server vs client generated ids, and I'm not pretending to know why, or to care particularly. It's not the point I'm making. Actions should be uniquely identified, and server applications should store and be able to repeat action responses.

Comment: This will only work for basic CRUD DB operations. Actually creating a resource on a server might involve much more like triggering a workflow on the backend. I doubt that simply replaying a response handles these cases.

Comment: @StefanHaberl Not at all. This pattern is all about app to app communication, and works equally well whatever the underlying action is: DB writes, file system writes, other api calls, whatever.

Answer (score 6):

You could try a two step approach. You request an object to be created, which returns a token. Then in a second request, ask for a status using the token. Until the status is requested using the token, you leave it in a "staged" state.

If the client disconnects after the first request, they won't have the token and the object stays "staged" indefinitely or until you remove it with another process.

If the first request succeeds, you have a valid token and you can grab the created object as many times as you want without it recreating anything.

There's no reason why the token can't be the ID of the object in the data store. You can create the object during the first request. The second request really just updates the "staged" field.

Comment: I should also mention that message queuing systems are designed to "guarantee" tasks are completed. Most use a similar 2-step approach, but hide it behind the interface. This is useful when communicating among services where work would otherwise be duplicated if a service died.

Comment: Is this something widely used in production, or something you came up with now? How does it compare to the solutions I came up with? It seems a lot more involved without a clear advantage, or did I miss something?

Comment: It is more work and I have used it in production. Most of the time I have an existing MQ in my infrastructure so I don't need to implement it explicitly.

Comment: There's always the logical conundrum of "if I ask it to update its status and the service dies, won't I end up creating a duplicate anyway?" This is where your code has to make sure it can recover the token first. If it can't, just start over from the beginning. If it can, just ask it to update the status upon restart (a no-op after the first attempt).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I would first do a "dummy" POST, to create an empty, dormant object, then send the actual data via PUT? The server would identify the dormant objects with a separate field. (And could periodically run batch jobs to clean them up.) I guess it would require all server code to take the dormant objects into account, which could be annoying.

Comment: You can actually completely create the object on the first round and return a legitimate ID. It can mean filtering *every* query for ever more. Another option is to have two sets of tables and move objects between them. Typically, you only need to do this for a handful of tables.

Comment: Just be careful to reuse the primary key from the staging table - otherwise we're back where we started.

Answer (score 4):

### Server-issued Identifiers

If you are dealing with the case where it is the server that issues the identifiers, create the object in a temporary, staged state. (This is an inherently non-idempotent operation, so it should be done with POST.) The client then has to do a further operation on it to transfer it from the staged state into the active/preserved state (which might be a PUT of a property of the resource, or a suitable POST to the resource).

Each client ought to be able to GET a list of their resources in the staged state somehow (maybe mixed with other resources) and ought to be able to DELETE resources they've created if they're still just staged. You can also periodically delete staged resources that have been inactive for some time.

You do not need to reveal one client's staged resources to any other client; they need exist globally only after the confirmatory step.

### Client-issued Identifiers

The alternative is for the client to issue the identifiers. This is mainly useful where you are modeling something like a filestore, as the names of files are typically significant to user code. In this case, you can use PUT to do the creation of the resource as you can do it all idempotently.

The down-side of this is that clients are able to create IDs, and so you have no control at all over what IDs they use.

Comment: The timeout for resources in the staged state will depend on the resources they use vs the resources you allocate to your application. Tune appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

There is another variation of this problem. Having a client generate a unique id indicates that we are asking a customer to solve this problem for us. Consider an environment where we have a publicly exposed APIs and have 100s of clients integrating with these APIs. Practically, we have no control over the client code and the correctness of his implementation of uniqueness. Hence, it would probably be better to have intelligence in understanding if a request is a duplicate. One simple approach here would be to calculate and store check-sum of every request based on attributes from a user input, define some time threshold (x mins) and compare every new request from the same client against the ones received in past x mins. If the checksum matches, it could be a duplicate request and add some challenge mechanism for a client to resolve this.
If a client is making two different requests with same parameters within x mins, it might be worth to ensure that this is intentional even if it's coming with a unique request id.
This approach may not be suitable for every use case, however, I think this will be useful for cases where the business impact of executing the second call is high and can potentially cost a customer. Consider a situation of payment processing engine where an intermediate layer ends up in retrying a failed requests OR a customer double clicked resulting in submitting two requests by client layer.

Answer (score 1):

### Design

- Automatic (without the need to maintain a manual black list)
- Memory optimized
- Disk optimized

### Algorithm [solution 1]

1. REST arrives with UUID
2. Web server checks if UUID is in Memory cache black list table (if yes, answer 409)
3. Server writes the request to DB (if was not filtered by ETS)
4. DB checks if the UUID is repeated before writing
5. If yes, answer 409 for the server, and blacklist to Memory Cache and Disk
6. If not repeated write to DB and answer 200

### Algorithm [solution 2]

1. REST arrives with UUID
2. Save the UUID in the Memory Cache table (expire for 30 days)
3. Web server checks if UUID is in Memory Cache black list table [return HTTP 409]
4. Server writes the request to DB [return HTTP 200]

In solution 2, the threshold to create the Memory Cache blacklist is created ONLY in memory, so DB will never be checked for duplicates. The definition of 'duplication' is "any request that comes into a period of time". We also replicate the Memory Cache table on the disk, so we fill it before starting up the server.

In solution 1, there will be never a duplicate, because we always check in the disk ONLY once before writing, and if it's duplicated, the next roundtrips will be treated by the Memory Cache. This solution is better for Big Query, because requests there are not imdepotents, but it's also less optmized.

[HTTP response code for POST when resource already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists)