# HTTP Request Automatic Retries

Tags: mysql, http, tomcat, networking, lan

how to prevent automatic repeat http request from client machine to tomcat server?

i have a problem in my live web applicaton working through local LAN.when a network failure occur sometimes multiple insertion take place in my mysql data base.
Any one know about these type of issues?
my application use tomcat as web sever and centos as interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159274/avoid-duplicate-posts-with-rest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid duplicate POSTs with REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159274/avoid-duplicate-posts-with-rest)