# Web API call sent 3 times in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

We are using Azure Web App Service to host our backend API in .NET 4.6.

We saw a particular web API ran 3 times exactly after 2 minutes interval. Out of those 3 runs, one should be triggered from the front end app (Angular 7 app hosted on Azure App Service). So the web API ran extra 2 times.

Observations:

1. This particular API ran for 8-10 minutes due to large number of files processing in each run. This was an exception generally it completes within a minute. All the required processing was done without any issue in three runs of API.
2. I verified the front end code and it won't call the API more than one. So I am not able to figure out why the API ran extra for 2 times? Is it due to any time out related setting in .NET or in Azure Web App?
3. This has not happened so far and is particularly observed for one specific person. May it be browser related issue?

Any pointer on how to segregate issue whether it is related to .NET/Azure application or something else would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly unlikely the API ran by itself unless its a time triggered function which can sometimes run under weird circomstances, but if its a HTTP triggered API 99.9% its your code calling it, just log the invocations and find out the details.

Comment: Thank you Matt! I will add logs in the respective places to check.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your suggestion. This was helpful. The issue seems to be from the browser/client. Referred the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159274/avoid-duplicate-posts-with-rest to fix the issue. Now I am sending client id that is set in front end code to the API and checking if the same client id already exists in records and in that case returning the required record details.